# How to split comma separated values to table in angular

Tags: angular

I have this csv files produced by my program. This file can be opened by excel correctly using the Data menu. My question is, how do I get this file into an angular table.

I have this to code to get the file and convert it into an array.

```
uploadListener($event: any): void {
        debugger;
        const text = [];
        const files = $event.srcElement.files;

        if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {
            const input = $event.target;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

            reader.onload = () => {
                debugger;
                const csvData = reader.result;
                const csvRecordsArray = (<string>csvData).split('/\r\n|\n/');

                const headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);

                this.records = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(
                    csvRecordsArray,
                    headersRow.length
                );
            };

            reader.onerror = function() {
                console.log('error is occured while reading file!');
            };
        } else {
            alert('Please import valid .csv file.');
            this.fileReset();
        }
    }

    getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any) {
        const csvArr = [];
debugger;
        for (let i = 1; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
            debugger;
            const curruntRecord = (<string>csvRecordsArray[i]).split(',');
            if (curruntRecord.length === headerLength) {
                const csvRecord: Transaction = new Transaction();
                csvRecord._amount = <number><any>curruntRecord[0].trim();
                csvRecord._orginId = <number><any>curruntRecord[16].trim();
                csvRecord._origin = curruntRecord[6].trim();
                csvRecord._dateAdded = curruntRecord[2].trim();
                csvRecord._timeAdded = curruntRecord[3].trim();
                csvRecord._vehicle = curruntRecord[9].trim();
                csvRecord._driver = curruntRecord[17].trim();
                csvRecord._conductor = curruntRecord[1].trim();
                csvRecord._destination = curruntRecord[4].trim();
                csvRecord._conductor = curruntRecord[1].trim();
                csvRecord._discount = <number><any>curruntRecord[11].trim();
                csvArr.push(csvRecord);
            }
        }
        console.log(csvArr);
        return csvArr;
    }

    isValidCSVFile(file: any) {
        return file.name.endsWith('.csv');
    }

    getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArr: any) {
        const headers = (<string>csvRecordsArr[0]).split(',');
        const headerArray = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            headerArray.push(headers[j]);
        }
        return headerArray;
    }
```

But all of my data is treated as one element of an array.
Please see the data that I am trying to load below:

```
""amount","conductor","dateAdded","timeAdded","destination","id","origin","passenger","type","vehicle","distance","incrementation","latittude","longitude","cityName","discount","originId","driver"
"10","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","09:54:08","A-1","1","A-0","1",,"A-0101","0","1","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","0","1","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"10","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","10:11:12","A-0","2","A-0","1",,"A-0101","0","4","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","0","2","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"12","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","12:04:09","A-4","3","A-0","1",,"A-0101","0","12","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","0","3","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"8","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","12:04:58","A-0","4","A-0","1","Senior/Student Discount","A-0101","0","13","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","2","4","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"13","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","12:08:59","A-5","5","A-0","1",,"A-0101","0","14","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","0","5","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"9.6","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","12:10:34","A-4","6","A-0","1","Senior/Student Discount","A-0101","0","15","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","2.4","6","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"10","Juan Dela Cruz","2020-01-31","13:11:55","A-0","7","A-0","1",,"A-0101","0","16","11.1915","125.004","Tacloban - Baybay S Rd, Tacloban City, Leyte, Philippines","0","7","Arturo A. Golong Jr."
"
```

Comment: use npm library [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Comment: i think your line endings got lost. Maybe this is interesting for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898036/how-to-keep-newline-characters-when-i-import-a-javascript-file-with-filereader

Comment: you just need to get the whole csv into a single string. for that you need to add single quotes in the beginning and the end of csv file data.once you have don now you need to split data with **'\n'** you will get all rows in an array. you can loop through this array. and in loop you need to split each row with **','** (comma) to get cell values. using loop you can now generate HTML table to your code and append it to any div.